# Getting Value (Description) of an object's property in another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I have to array of objects which can be related to each other through CategoryId. like below code:

```
const Category = [
    { ID: 100 , Description: Cate1}, 
    {ID: 101 , Description: Cate2}
]
const Items = [ 
    {ID: 2001, CategoryID: 100, Desc: Item1 }, 
    {ID: 2002, CategoryID: 100, Desc: Item2 }, 
    {ID: 2003, CategoryID: 101, Desc: Item3 }, 
]
```

I am going to distribute items by the use of map method in lis that are summarized in their own ul according to the category descriptions that are extracted from category id   which exists in both arrays. For example:

```
Cate1 > ul
  item1 > li
  item2 > li
Cate2 > ul
  item3 > li
```

.
.
.
How can I tackle this issue with Javascript or ES6/7/8?

Comment: Use `Category.forEach()` to loop through the category list. Inside that use `Items.forEach()` and test if the item's category ID matches the current category from the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at each category and for each one [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the matching items. This is easy, but will be a little slow if you have lots of data because you loop though the item list every time:

```js
const Category = [{ ID: 100 , Description: 'Cate1'}, {ID: 101 , Description: 'Cate2'}]
const Items = [ {ID: 2001, 'CategoryID': 100, Desc: 'Item1' }, {ID: 2002, 'CategoryID': 100, Desc: 'Item2' }, {ID: 2003, 'CategoryID': 101, Desc: 'Item3' }, ]

Category.forEach(cat => {
    console.log('ul> '+cat.Description)
    Items.filter(item => item.CategoryID === cat.ID)
    .forEach(item => console.log('   li> ' + item.Desc))
})
```

Alternatively you can build a lookup table for your items base on ID once, and then use it to find the items in constant time. This will be faster with larger data, but requires a little more work upfront:

```js
const Category = [{ ID: 100 , Description: 'Cate1'}, {ID: 101 , Description: 'Cate2'}]
const Items = [ {ID: 2001, 'CategoryID': 100, Desc: 'Item1' }, {ID: 2002, 'CategoryID': 100, Desc: 'Item2' }, {ID: 2003, 'CategoryID': 101, Desc: 'Item3' }, ]


let lookup = Items.reduce((a, c) => {
    (a[c.CategoryID] || (a[c.CategoryID] = [])).push(c)
    return a
}, {})

Category.forEach(cat => {
    console.log('ul> '+cat.Description)
    lookup[cat.ID]
    .forEach(item => console.log('   li> ' + item.Desc))
})
```

Comment: can we use ES8 methods such as object.entries for simplifying the code?

Comment: Hey @Xman2018 that's a good questions … I think in this case they won't simplify much because you are starting with an array of objects and functions like `Object.entries` are used to make arrays from objects and their properties.

Comment: Hey @Mark Meyer, Thank you for your reply. Could you please introduce a beneficial reference for using reduce method and Object Entries in reactjs from scratch? I know what the reduce method does in JS while I cannot understand the concept of using it on array of object to summarize them.